# How to create current date folder from ffmpeg command

Tags: ffmpeg

I am  writing a code for ffmpeg command .But i want the value to be stored in current date folder . is there any way to create current date folder in ffmpeg command . not in Batch files .

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
#!/bin/bash

now=$(date +"%m_%d_%Y")
outdir=/pathtodirectory/$now

if [[ ! -d "$outdir" ]]; then
  mkdir -p "$outdir"
fi

ffmpeg -i input "$outdir"/output
```

Comment: yes you can create a batch file and run it on command line right

Comment: ok..i will try that . But can you tell me that is it possible to create the date folder from the commandline or not